# No UIInterfaceOrientation value when adding new key to info.plist

Tags: xcode4.2

I want my app to launch in landscape mode and according to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html

I should add a UIInterfaceOrientation key to the info.plist, but if I right-click while in the info.plist and select  add row I get a drop down menu of names to give the key but UIInterfaceOrientation isn't among them.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click to the white area below the keys/values in info.plist file in Xcode, and enable  "Show Raw Keys/Values".